# How to convert S3object to Observable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rx-java, vert.x

I'm trying to implement a method with *RxJava* and *Vert.x* framework.

The method has `Observable<String>` as its return type, but when fetching some data from S3 bucket within the method bogy, it returns`S3Object`.

Now, I have to covert `S3Object` to `Observable<string>`. (I store *JSON* like abc.json in S3 bucket).

```java
 public Observable<String> getCustomerFroms3(String orderId) {

    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials (
           "*************MIIVCCCA",
            "az4aBUp58x&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3gUTw"
    );
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider (credentials))
            .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
            .build();

    String bucketName = "database8";
    S3Object s3Object = s3client.getObject(bucketName,orderId);
    System.out.println(s3Object);

}
```

How I could convert `S3Object` to `Observable`?

Comment: You could use `Observable.fromCallable` though doesn't support cancellation if the s3 download takes a while. If that's an issue can advise.

Comment: why should this be an observable? You're not observing anything

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach would be to use the `Observable` factory method to create simple instance out of the `S3Object` content:

```java
public Observable<String> getCustomerFroms3(String orderId) {
    return Observable.create(
          s -> {
              try {
                  AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials (
                        "*************MIIVCCCA",
                        "az4aBUp58x&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&3gUTw"
                  );
                  AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                        .standard()
                        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider (credentials))
                        .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
                        .build();

                  S3Object s3Object = s3client.getObject("database8", orderId);
                  s.onNext(IOUtils.toString(s3Object.getObjectContent()));
                  s.onComplete();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  s.onError(e);
              }
          }
    );
}
```

*Note that this is only to demonstrate the approach to create the `Observable` instance and should not be considered as an optimal option.*

Comment: Very nice, then it should be fine accepting and up-voting the answer ;)